# Is there a way to change the date to a day of a protocol in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a very large data set of Subjects who underwent two Protocols.
Here is an example df:

```
df <- data.frame (Subject = c('875','875','875','875','875','875','875','875',
                              '875','1392','1392','1392','1392','1392','1392',
                              '1392','1392','1392','1392','1392'), 
                  StartDate = c('20160915','20160916','20160917','20160918',
                                '20160926','20160927','20160928','20160929',
                                '20160930','20160917','20160918','20160919',
                                '20160920','20160921','20160922','20161005',
                                '20161006','20161007','20161008','20161009'),
                  Protocol = c('Training','Training','Training','Training',
                               'Test','Test','Test','Test','Test','Training',
                               'Training','Training','Training','Training',
                               'Training','Test','Test','Test','Test','Test'),
                  Points = c('14','32','33','50','41','56','41','48','49','34',
                              '16','25','21','34','28','61','24','45','45','47'),
                  Attempts = c('24','45','37','69','56','59','53','67','53','55',
                              '34','36','26','48','44','64','36','62','53','55'))
```

I would like to take the StartDate of each Protocol and change it to a Day of Testing, or even just add in a column with Day of Testing.

There are irregular days for each Protocol, so a simple numbering is not working. And the actual df has thousands of rows, so doing it by hand would be a nightmare. I am looking to be able to compare specific days of a protocol between subjects (ie Day 3 of Training between subjects, etc.)

I would like to change the data frame to look like:

```
df2 <- data.frame (Subject = c('875','875','875','875','875','875','875','875',
                              '875','1392','1392','1392','1392','1392','1392',
                              '1392','1392','1392','1392','1392'), 
                  StartDate = c('20160915','20160916','20160917','20160918',
                                '20160926','20160927','20160928','20160929',
                                '20160930','20160917','20160918','20160919',
                                '20160920','20160921','20160922','20161005',
                                '20161006','20161007','20161008','20161009'),
                  Day = c('1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4','5','1','2','3',
                          '4','5','6','1','2','3','4','5'),
                  Protocol = c('Training','Training','Training','Training',
                               'Test','Test','Test','Test','Test','Training',
                               'Training','Training','Training','Training',
                               'Training','Test','Test','Test','Test','Test'),
                  Points = c('14','32','33','50','41','56','41','48','49','34',
                              '16','25','21','34','28','61','24','45','45','47'),
                  Attempts = c('24','45','37','69','56','59','53','67','53','55',
                              '34','36','26','48','44','64','36','62','53','55'))
```

Is there a way to do this? Or does anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *"There are irregular days for each Protocol"*?

Assuming you have your data ordered by `StartDate`. You could do this

```
df %>%
  group_by(Subject, Protocol) %>%
  mutate(Day = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

```
# A tibble: 20 × 6
   Subject StartDate Protocol Points Attempts   Day
   <fct>   <fct>     <fct>    <fct>  <fct>    <int>
 1 875     20160915  Training 14     24           1
 2 875     20160916  Training 32     45           2
 3 875     20160917  Training 33     37           3
 4 875     20160918  Training 50     69           4
 5 875     20160926  Test     41     56           1
 6 875     20160927  Test     56     59           2
 7 875     20160928  Test     41     53           3
 8 875     20160929  Test     48     67           4
 9 875     20160930  Test     49     53           5
10 1392    20160917  Training 34     55           1
11 1392    20160918  Training 16     34           2
12 1392    20160919  Training 25     36           3
13 1392    20160920  Training 21     26           4
14 1392    20160921  Training 34     48           5
15 1392    20160922  Training 28     44           6
16 1392    20161005  Test     61     64           1
17 1392    20161006  Test     24     36           2
18 1392    20161007  Test     45     62           3
19 1392    20161008  Test     45     53           4
20 1392    20161009  Test     47     55           5
```